# Can't Use JS Modules: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, mime-types, es6-modules, anime.js

everyone. I'm really new to Javascript — just starting to learn, really. I've got a simple HTML file I want to run below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module">
            import anime from "../node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.es.js";
          
            anime({
                targets: 'div',
                translateX: 250,
                rotate: '1turn',
                backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                duration: 800
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use anime.js, run its "hello world" script. I have it downloaded to my computer, to the directory seen above. I am running this html through *live-server,* so I don't have to deal with CORS issues.

However, every method I try to import this module doesn't work. I always get "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec" in the Chrome console whenever I try to serve this html page. To make matters weirder, whenever I attempt to click the *anime.es.js:1* link Chrome returns, in the applications tab it shows me my HTML file above.

Have I missed a specific step here, or something?

Comment: Sometimes an HTML mime type indicates the server sent an error page after an invalid request. What's the response code shown on the network tab of browser tools when the import statement gets executed?

Comment: It's giving me a status of "304 Not Modified," and the response is my HTML file. It seems to think my HTML file is the Javascript module ... which doesn't make any sense to me, as they're in different directories.

Comment: Try resolving the relative URL for the module file into an absolute URL based on the location of the HTML file. Paste the absolute URL into the browser's address bar and visit it. If you see the JavaScript file then that's not the problem. If you see the HTML file the `../` part of the JS url may be invalid: **if** the HTML file is in the **server root** folder, it's parent directory will not be accessible from the web. If so you may be seeing the default page served when accessing the server root folder.

Comment: ... actually accessing a `node-modules` directory from the front end would be unusual. If it's not within the public directory  structure you can't access it using the `../` style relative url from the web.